# Ctrl+Shift+F10 equivalent in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Used to be quite happy with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> shortcut in VS2008 to get at the right click menu after typing something that wasn't recognised to quickly resolve it. This doesn't work in VS2010! Anyone know the VS2010 equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'context-menu' key does the job I believe

Comment: It does! NB: it works in VS2008 too - can't believe i've been using Ctrl+Shift+F10 all this time when I could have just used that single button :(

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl-dot "." should do it I think

Comment: That brings up View.ShowSmartTag which is auto completion.

Comment: +1 - it's not the same as the full menu that used to come up but it is exactly what I wanted it for

Comment: Yeah, control "." brings up the more context sensitive version, which is nicer.